# Google Assistant SDK on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: raspberry-pi2, google-assistant-sdk

Does the Google Assistant SDK also work on a "Pi 2 Model B" (ARM Cortex-A7, a 32bit processor), or is a "Pi 3 Model B" ( ARM Cortex-A53, 64bit processor) essential to get the SDK up and running  ?

Comment: It should, did you have any error when trying?

Comment: It does, I got it working. Just follow the instructions!

Comment: I just finished setting it up on my RPi 2 using a usb camera with built in mic (don't have a USB mic yet)... seems to work fine. It gives a warning when it first starts but does not affect it after...

Comment: Nice! Can you post an answer to your own question with your findings?

Answer (score 1):

It's working properly on a Raspberry Pi 2. I'm using it with my Logitech c920's mic.

Answer (score 0):

I am running the Voice Kit that was in the MagPi Magazine on a Raspberry PI Zero W, so it should run fine on almost all the Pi's https://aiyprojects.withgoogle.com/voice/

Comment: Not any longer with the latest upgrades for late May.

Comment: Indeed the latest update breaks the compatibility with other pi's other than the pi 3.
However, I read in the docs that you could compile and run for 'other platforms', no idea what will and what won't work though