# Google Assistant fails on RPi2 with print error

Tags: raspberry-pi2, python-venv, google-assistant-sdk

Managed to get through most of the install until the end when attempting to run the sample.

```
python -m googlesamples.assistant.auth_helpers --client-secrets /home/pi/client_secret.json

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 151, in _run_module_as_main
mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 118, in _get_module_details
return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 104, in _get_module_details
spec = importlib.util.find_spec(mod_name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/util.py", line 86, in find_spec
parent = __import__(parent_name, fromlist=['__path__'])
File "/home/pi/google/lib/python3.4/site-packages/googlesamples/assistant/auth_helpers/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
import google.auth.transport.grpc
File "/home/pi/google/lib/python3.4/site-packages/google/auth/transport/grpc.py", line 20, in <module>
import grpc
File "/home/pi/google/lib/python3.4/site-packages/grpc/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
from grpc._cython import cygrpc as _cygrpc
File "src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.pyx", line 32, in init grpc._cython.cygrpc (src/python/grpcio/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.c:28305)
File "/home/pi/google/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3036, in <module>
@_call_aside
File "/home/pi/google/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3020, in _call_aside
f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/pi/google/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3064, in _initialize_master_working_set
for dist in working_set
File "/home/pi/google/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3064, in <genexpr>
for dist in working_set
File "/home/pi/google/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2594, in activate
declare_namespace(pkg)
File "/home/pi/google/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2162, in declare_namespace
_handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
File "/home/pi/google/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2097, in _handle_ns
loader.load_module(packageName)
File "./google.py", line 42
print head,body,tail

SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'
```

Saw one [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43682056/google-assistant-sdk-on-raspberry-pi-2/43812210) where a few have got it work but it's not clear to me if they're using a python2 or 3 venv? Can anyone assist?

Comment: I just followed the instruction line by line for python 3:
https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/prototype/getting-started-pi-python/run-sample

Comment: did you create a file named google.py in your current directory? It might conflict with the `google.assistant` namespace used by the SDK.

Comment: Thanks @proppy for the catch. I had an old script that made use of another google API. Since I changed the name it works just fine.

Comment: Happy to help! Can you make sure to close your question?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you had a file named `google.py` in the same directory which was conflicating with the `google.*` [python namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/namespace_packages/).

Answer (score 0):

See @proppy reply above in comments. Would've closed earlier but I only received notification for the answer but not the comments???